# Replacing numbers to text using conditionals

Tags: r

Here is a vector containing values ranging from 0 to 1:

```
a <- runif(100, 0, 1)
```

I want to do the following conversion

```
>= 0.975 becomes AA+  
<= 0.025 becomes AA-  
< 0.975 && > 0.025 becomes AA
a[a >= 0.975] = 'AA+'  
sum(a == 'AA+')  
3

a[a <= 0.025] = 'AA-'  
sum(a == 'AA-')   
2

a[a > 0.025 && a < 0.975] = 'AA'  
sum(a == 'AA')  
100
```

In other words:

```
a

[1] "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA"
 [16] "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA"
 [31] "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA"
 [46] "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA"
 [61] "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA"
 [76] "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA"
 [91] "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA"
```

I am baffled by why this is happening.  Why is `AA` overwriting the first two conversions?

Comment: use `&` instead of `&&`

Comment: @akrun. What is the difference of those two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that as soon as you do:

```
a[a >= 0.975] = 'AA+'
```

the entire vector `a` is converted to character which is not really desirable.  It would be better to do it this way:

```
aa <- character(length(a))  # pre-allocate aa
aa[a >= 0.975] <- "AA+"
aa[a > 0.025 & a < 0.975] <- "AA"  # note &, not &&
aa[a <= 0.025] <- "AA-"
```

Here are some alternatives:

**1) cut** `cut` will work except that the value 0.975 will be assigned "AA":

```
cut(a, c(0, 0.025, 0.975, 1), lab = c("AA-", "AA", "AA+"))
```

**2) subscript**

```
c("AA-", "AA", "AA+")[ 1 + (a > 0.025) + (a >= 0.975) ]
```

**3) ifelse**

```
ifelse(a <= 0.025, "AA-", ifelse(a < 0.975, "AA", "AA+"))
```

**4) case_when**

```
library(dplyr)

case_when( a <= 0.025 ~ "AA-",
           a < 0.975 ~ "AA",
           TRUE ~ "AA+")
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** **Modified original solution** We need to use single `&` instead of `&&`

```
a[a > 0.025 & a < 0.975] = 'AA'   
table(a)
# a
#  AA AA- AA+ 
#  92   5   3
```

**2)**  **Explanation** According to `?"&"`

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The
>   shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as
>   arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right
>   examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds
>   only until the result is determined

The difference is very easy to understand i.e. the output of logical condition is a single element

```
a > 0.025 && a < 0.975
#[1] TRUE
```

which does the recycling and all the elements are replaced with `'AA'`

whereas if we do

```
a > 0.025 & a < 0.975
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [13]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [25]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [37] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [49]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [61]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [73]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [85]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [97]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**3)**  **Alternative solution** If we need to use a better approach, there is `findInterval`

```
c("AA-", "AA", "AA+")[findInterval(a, c(0, 0.025, 0.975))]
```

**4)** **replace**  Another option is with `replace`

```
library(dplyr) #for chaining
replace(a, a >= 0.975, 'AA+') %>%
       replace(., .<= 0.025, 'AA-') %>% 
       replace(., . >0.025 & . < 0.975, 'AA')
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
a <- runif(100, 0, 1)
a[a >= 0.975] = 'AA+'
a[a <= 0.025] = 'AA-'
```

Comment: whats the difference between `&` and `&&`?